# Changing query ordering based on whether a variable equals 1 or 0

Tags: php, mysql

For the query below, I would like to change the way the results are ordered.

Right now, the results are ordered by `ORDER BY most_recent DESC`.   I would like to keep this ordering, but I would like any row where `s.topten` =  1 to be ordered above rows where `s.topten` =  0.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT s.loginid, s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, s.datesubmitted, l.username,
  s.submissionid, s.subcheck, s.topten, COUNT(c.commentid) countComments, 
  GREATEST(s.datesubmitted, COALESCE(MAX(c.datecommented), s.datesubmitted)) AS most_recent
FROM submission s
INNER JOIN login l ON s.loginid = l.loginid
LEFT OUTER JOIN comment c ON s.submissionid = c.submissionid
GROUP BY s.submissionid
ORDER BY most_recent DESC
LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statement in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY case when s.topten = 1 then 0 else 1 end, 
 most_recent DESC
```

Comment: Thanks... this looks promising... does it keep the ordering by most_recent amongst rows where s.topten = 1?